# Max CPU% on Continuous WebJob

Tags: azure-webjobssdk, kudu, azure-app-service-plans

I have a continuous webjob running that reads messages from a queue, reads a file from Blob Storage, converts it, and then writes the converted file to a different blob container. All of the files are being converted properly. The Kudu site for my app service is running at nearly 100%. The process explorer in Kudu shows my webjob as the only other process running within that server. Conventional wisdom indicates that it is probably the webjob that is the problem. Are there any tools for determining what the problem might be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to download a process dump (From Kudu process explorer), and then analyze it locally, e.g. with windbg or Visual Studio. By looking at the threads, you should be able to identify which ones are actively spinning CPU.

Another simple test is to temporarily stop creating new blobs, and check whether that causes the CPU usage to go down. If it's still high in the absence of any processing, then something strange is going on.